# responsive tabs (tab to accordion on small screen width)

Tags: theming

I have a task of building a responsive website with custom theme and all that good stuff. One thing I stumbled across is using tabs to display data.

Tabs are a requirement in the site but they are not responsive. I have seen some wordpress sites that have this nice feature of turning tabs into accordion when the screen width is small.

Unfortunately I could not find a way to implement that in Drupal so far. The only way that I thought of is loading to view blocks (1 tabs and 1 accordion) and show/hide one of the two based on screen width using JS but this solution is not an efficient one.

Please let me know if there is a way in which I can accomplish this task.

Comment: Hi redamakarem, can I have your feedback ? did you try the solutions purposed ?

Comment: hey sorry for the late reply but nope the proposed solutions didnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

Short way : download [Easy Responsive Tabs to Accordion](http://webtrendset.com/demo/easy-responsive-tabs/Index.html) Jquery plugin, add it to your theme and call the `easyResponsiveTabs` function for your HTML tabs markup.

**Drupal Solution with Panels :** use [Panels responsive tabs to accordion](https://drupal.org/sandbox/kojo/2223297), a sandbox project which provides a Responsive Tabs to Accordion Panel style.

1. Install [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels/) module.
2. Install the sandbox project. This was a quick done project (no time to develop the admin options) so you may have to modify a few lines in `responsive_tabs.inc` to set up the paths to css or js files and/or HTML markup in `responsive_tabstoaccordion_panels.js`.
3. Go to  your region Panel style and choose the new style **Responsive Tabs to Accordion**

[image: tabs display]
[image: accordion display]